# Jython Jar Dependency Import Failure

Tags: java, python, jython

I have an application in a jar that depends on a handful of libraries in different jars.

Here's my issue:
when I import just my main application file, jython appears to load the class correctly, but complains about a missing class via a NoClassDefError (one expressed in one of the supporting library jars).

However, If I now add that jar to the classpath, Jython can no longer find the original import, and complains: `ImportError: No module named edu`

My code:

```
import sys 

def setClassPath():
     libDir = "/Users/gestalt/Documents/msmexplorer_git/msmexplorer/MSMExplorer/"
     classPaths = [ 
          "dist/MSMExplorer.jar"
          "dist/lib/prefuse.jar" #the missing class is here, but this line causes package edu to go missing
     ]   
     for classPath in classPaths:
          sys.path.append(libDir+classPath)

def runJavaClass():
     from edu.stanford.folding.msmexplorer import MSMExplorer
     me = MSMExplorer()

def main():
     setClassPath()
     runJavaClass()

if __name__ == "__main__":
     main()
```

Thanks!

Comment: Does this warrant a Java tag?

Comment: @Duncan as some of this come down to jar-wrangling and java classpath issues, I think it's not unreasonable

Answer (score 0):

Stupid as it may sound, this was some sort of peculiar syntax error. A comma is necessary between the jar specs:

```
"dist/MSMExplorer.jar",
"dist/lib/prefuse.jar"
```

Comment: Yep, Python (and so Jython) implicitly joins strings together into one string if there is only whitespace in between. Most of the time this is very convenient :)